# Can't start mysql server on OpenSUSE 13.2

Tags: opensuse, mysql

Try to start the server:

```
# service mysql start
```

Output:

```
Job for mysql.service failed. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xn" for details.
```

Output for "systemctl status mysql.service":

```
mysql.service - MySQL server
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Seg 2015-02-16 20:11:32 BRST; 1min 1s ago
 Process: 25103 ExecStart=/usr/lib/mysql/rcmysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

And /var/run/mysql don't have any log.

I'm using MariaDB server.

Comment: Can you run the server's binary directly from the command line? Maybe with more debugging flags? Might give you some more information.

Comment: Check the daemon syslog.